# What was the first Lisp implementation that could generate machine code?

Tags: history, compilers, lisp

LISP is considered by some to be primarily an interpreted language, but compilers
have been made for it. What was the first compiler?

To be clear, this is about compilers that compile LISP code stored for interpretation (whether as S-expressions, ASTs or some other internal form) to machine code, such that it then runs faster than the interpreted form did. It's not about "dumpers" that simply remove a parsing step or other such mechanisms.

Comment: "LISP is generally considered an interpreted language" – I would hope that *at least* the people who use Lisp would know that there *is no such thing* as an "interpreted language" and that this term is so non-sensical that it is Not Even Wrong.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Don't be disingenuous, please.  "An interpreted language" means exactly what it intuitively seems like it means: a language where the primary intended use case is as an interpreted language.  Saying "there's no such thing because it's theoretically possible to compile anything that can be interpreted and vice versa" is pedantic and obnoxious, and serves no purpose other than to derail conversations and annoy people.

Comment: <troll>There's never been a LISP compiler. LISP "compilers" just dump memory. See the Emacs "nonportable dumper" catastrophe that was only fixed in the last couple years.

Comment: @R, what does the Emacs dumper have to do with whether or not any compiler for any LISP variant has ever been written?

Comment: As a side note, there are nifty things you can do via partial evaluation and interpreters, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_evaluation

Comment: @SolomonSlow: It's not proof that one hasn't. It's an example of the mechanism that's usually used in place of compilers for lisp.

Comment: @R.. No, it's an example of a mechanism that's used in **addition** to compilers for lisp.

Comment: "LISP is generally considered an interpreted language" - that's a misconception and often confuses compilation and interactive use. Lisp had compilers early on, even the first self-hosted compiler and some implementations are compiler only. Still most implementations can be interactive used due to incremental compilation: a Lisp compiler can usually compile anything from single expressions and often compiles directly into memory. Thus Lisp is often interactive AND compiled. That one can interactively use Lisp does not mean that a certain implementation is using an interpreter.

Comment: @RainerJoswig Sure it's a misconception, at least to some degree. Demonstrating that is the whole point of this question and answer.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**The first LISP compiler was implemented very early in the life of
the first LISP, [LISP I for the IBM 704](http://www.softwarepreservation.org/projects/LISP/lisp15_family/).**

---

#### The LISP I Compiler

From the [*LISP I Programmer's Manual*](http://bitsavers.org/pdf/mit/rle_lisp/LISP_I_Programmers_Manual_Mar60.pdf) (March 1, 1960)
section 4.2, "Definitions of Functions in LISP"

> In Chapter 2 functions are connected to their names only through the
>   use of the form LABEL. In the current LISP system, there are two
>   further ways a function can be defined:
>
> The first of these relates to functions defined in the system by
>   machine-language subroutines. Such a subroutine for a function may
>   be already available as part of the LISP system itself, in which
>   case it appears among the functions given in Section 9, or it may
>   have been produced by the LISP compiler.

Section 4.6, "The Compiler," describes its operation in detail:

> The LISP compiler is itself a pseudo-funciton which is available to
>   the APPLY operator. The compiler is called in by the LISP function,
>
> *comdef*[x],
>
> where x is a list of names of the functions to be compiled. Each
>   function on the list will be compiled into a binary machine
>   program....

The compiler runs in several stages: producing a (LISP) list of
assembly instructions, a two-pass assembly of this list to binary
code, and then binding the name in the system so it calls the
machine-language code rather than the original S-expression. The
assembly code list looks like:

```
(( ,LXD,0,4),( ,TXI,G0007,4,-1),( ,TRA,*+5),(G0008,BSS,0),...)
```

This appears also to be the first use of something like
[`gensym`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30108137/107294): "In this example, the objects beginning with G are
atomic symbols generated for use within the compiler."

"Linking" was done at compile time, so one had to be careful of order
when compiling functions in separate `comdef`s, though circular
references were fine if done within a single compile run:

> If a function f uses a function g as a subfuction, then g should be
>   included in a *comdef* which comes before the *comdef* involving f
>   *except* in the following special case: if a closed circle of
>   function usage occurs, e.g.
>
> f₁ uses f₂
>                         f₂ uses f₃
>                         .
>                         .
>                         .
>                         fₙ uses f₁,
>
> then all of the functions in this circle must be compiled in the
>   same *comdef*. thus the functions listed in a given *comdef* should
>   be unrelated or related in this circular sense.

---

#### The LISP 1.5 Compiler

The compiler was actively maintained and extended for at least several
years. [AIM-039](ftp://publications.ai.mit.edu/ai-publications/pdf/AIM-039.pdf), "Artificial Intelligence Project--RLE and MIT
Computation Center Memo 39--The New Compiler," by T. Hart and M. Levin
has no date, but from its [sequence in the AIM list](http://publications.csail.mit.edu/ai/browse/0000browse.shtml) it
appears to have been written sometime between January 1962 (AIM-31)
and October 1962 (AIM-46). By this point the compiler had become
self-hosting:

> This memo introduces the brand new LISP 1.5 Compiler designed and
>   programmed by Tim Hart and Mike Leven. It is written entirely in
>   LISP and is the first compiler that has ever compiled itself by
>   being executed interpretively.
>
> The purpose of the LISP Compiler is to replace S-expression
>   definitions of functions with efficient machine language
>   subroutines. A subroutine can be expected to run about 40 times as
>   fast as the interpreter can execute the same function from its
>   S-expression definition. Subroutines typically take 70-80 per cent
>   of the storage required by their corresponding S-expressions.
>
> The compiler as it exists on the standard compiler tape is a machine
>   language program that was obtained by having the S-expression
>   definition of the compiler work on itself through the interpreter.
>
> The compiler is designed so that compiled functions and interpretal
>   [sic] functions can be intermixed freely. Suitable declarations
>   allow free variables to be transmitted between the compiled
>   functions and the interpreter.

There were some interesting limitations to the compiler, perhaps for
performance reasons. For example, checks for the existence of free
variables used by the compiled functions seem to have been left out.
From section "Free Variables":

> When a variable is used free, it must have been bound by a higher
>   level function. If a program is being run interpretively, and a free
>   variable is used without having been bound on a higher level, error
>   diagnostic *A  8* will occur.
>
> If the program is being run compiled, the diagnostic may not occur,
>   and the variable may have value NIL.
>
> *All free variables in compiled programs must be declared SPECIAL or
>   COMMON.*

Comment: Re, "interesting limitations to the compiler."  IIRC, One of the innovations of [Common Lisp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Lisp) was the explicit requirement that compiling a function should not change its behavior in any way. Prior to that, programmers using certain LISP systems had to be aware of subtle behavioral differences between compiled code and interpreted code. (e.g., [meaning of "local" variables in MacLisp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maclisp#Characteristics).)

Comment: I now have a page describing the internals of the LISP 1.5 compiler in detail, for anyone interested: https://texdraft.github.io/lisp-compiler/internals.html